# Is it possible to export my website to a native iOS/Android application?

Tags: importing-exporting

I'm new to the [EZPublish CMS](http://ez.no/) and I see that he give you the facility to export your website into an Android or iPhone application.

Is there any way to do the same with Drupal?

Answer (score 5):

[Mobile App Generator](https://drupal.org/project/mag) exports a website to plain .html pages so that [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) can compile it into native mobile apps.

> Mobile App Generator assists in creating native multi-platform
>   PhoneGap mobile applications for Apple iOS(iPhone, iPad), Google
>   Android, Palm, Symbian, BlackBerry and more.

If you want to manage the website through mobile App then take a look at this module [Drupad](https://drupal.org/project/drupad)

> Drupad.module is the companion module for the iPhone™ / iPod touch™
>   application

Comment: so everytime i add content i have to regenerate the app?

Comment: @mohammedaminebourkadi No, not like that, once you added all the content then you generate the app

Comment: and what if i add another content after generating the app?

Comment: @mohammedaminebourkadi check this video it will help you in all the way  ----  http://denver2012.drupal.org/program/sessions/auto-generate-your-mobile-drupal-app-using-phonegap

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manage your Drupal 8 website through mobile App then take a look at this android app https://github.com/onedrupal/One-Drupal-Android

In play store at https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.technikh.onedrupal&pcampaignid=MKT-Other-global-all-co-prtnr-py-PartBadge-Mar2515-1

Companion drupal module https://www.drupal.org/project/one_api

Login, Create & edit nodes, Upload images, Publish, Unpublish, Promote to front page, remove from front page(Demote)....