# How can I make a mobile app that is basically a mobile browser to access my live Drupal site?

Tags: theming

There is a question about [exporting Drupal pages for use in a mobile app](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/74859/is-it-possible-to-export-my-website-to-a-native-ios-android-application), but I would like to know if there is an easy way to make a mobile app (iOS, Android, etc.) that simply loads the existing site in a browser for online-only access.

I looked into Phonegap, but (as far as I can tell) you have to export the pages as HTML for that.  However, the primary purpose of my site is to send messages back and forth using the [Private Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/privatemsg) module, so making the site accessible offline makes no sense.

I already have a responsive theme, so the site also looks decent in mobile browsers.  I just want a mobile app because I want the site to appear in App Store and Google Play searches.

Is there a straightforward way to address this use case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no module(convenient) to build all apps in Drupal, You have to build your own or if you have a mobile site then you can do it without Drupal help, see my article for [android app](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Free-Android-App-for-Your-Mobile-Site-with-AppsGeyser). There are so  many builders like [iBuildApp](http://ibuildapp.com/), [Appypie](http://www.appypie.com/), [Como](http://www.como.com/), and [so many](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=create%20mobile%20app&safe=active&start=10).

Comment: Also bear in mind that Apple will flat out reject an app that's just a webview proxying a website. It needs to be converted to a native app if you want to get it into the app store. Android is more forgiving, as you'd expect.